# Vader sentiment analysis

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, french, vader

I'm using [Vader](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment) in Python to perform sentiment analysis. Is there a way to analyze different languages than English (I need French in this case)

If yes, how do I do it, or what do I need?

Comment: Vader is largely dependent on a sentiment lexicon built for English. You won't be able to use Vader unless there's a french version of the lexicon.